# Quick Action Button in Case Screen

Tags: quickaction

I have created a Quick Action button and Placed in Case Details page in lightning. It does not show up in the page. Can you please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have taken all necessary steps and the button still does not show up, check this out if it helps you.

- [Quick Action/Custom buttons not visible in Lightning Experience for Users](https://jdspaceit.wordpress.com/2017/10/10/actioncustom-buttons-not-visible-in-lightning-experience-for-users/)

You need to do one of the two things:

- Enable "Allow WebLink access via the Tooling API" permission on the affected profiles.
- Enabling "View Setup and Configuration" perm for the affected user will result in quick actions being visible (this may not be the best route as you may not want end users to have access to setup)

There's a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCYiQAM&title=custom-quick-action-is-not-visible-for-affected-profiles-in-the-page-layout-in-lightning-experience-in-winter-18) for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

"Allow WebLink access via the Tooling API" permission has a new name now:
Allow Access to Customized Actions